# How to expose a public Microservice without any authentication at all?

Tags: jhipster

I have a public Microservice that I want to expose to the world. When creating a Microservice application we always get the question :

```
? (6/16) Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? (Use arrow keys)
❯ JWT authentication (stateless, with a token) 
  [BETA] Authentication with JHipster UAA server (the server must be generated separately)
```

But what about having a "No Authentication" option (like "No" registry or "No database") ? This would get rid of a few lines of code and Spring Security configuration.

WDYT ?

Comment: It should be done very carefully because even if your API is public, don't forget about actuator endpoints, you would not want anyone be able to read your config or to trigger an application context refresh. I would rather keep security and unprotect my API endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom RestController and set a mapping different from /api/*** because it's only path prefixed by /api that are secure.